# Compress each directory to its own Zip file from command line

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, compression, zip

I have a directory of directories. I want to compress each of them in to its own zip file, keeping the same name.

I don't want it to be recursive, I just want to compress dozens of folders in the same directory with one command.

For example, input is three directories containing files:

- `/test1`
- `/test2`
- `/test3`

Output is:

- `test1.zip`
- `test2.zip`
- `test3.zip`

How can I do this from the command line in macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@mark-adler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler) (for providing a now deleted answer), this did the trick:

```
for x in *; zip -r $x.zip $x
```

Comment: Who is mark-adler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler

Comment: And what does Mark Adler have to do with this question? Did he post an answer on Stack Overflow that helped you? Can you please edit your question to add a link to that answer?

Comment: Yes, but the question is deleted from Stack Overflow--not a programming question, just coding. No answer to link to.

Comment: Fair enough. I contextually linked him in the answer and explain who it is.